# UITabBarController based app: preferred login functionality

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

Here are two ways to implement a login page for a `UITabBarController` based ios application:

1) use the AppDelegate.m file's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method and **if** *logged* in, set `self.window.rootViewController = self.yourTabBarController`, **if** *not logged* in, set `self.window.rootViewController = self.yourLoginViewController`

or

2) use the AppDelegate.m file's `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` method to simply call `[self presentViewController:self.yourLoginViewController animated:NO completion:nil];`, where `self.window.rootViewController = self.yourTabBarController` is only set once, and you simply `dismissViewControllerAnimated:` to "yourLoginViewController" when a successful login executes.

Which one of these methodologies is better? And why?

Comment: Based on performance optimization, this is not opinion-based. One will in fact perform faster than the other due to animation-time-delay, granted the animations are passed YES.

Answer (score 3):

First of all I think you have your second option backwards (I would think you would want the root to be the tab bar controller, and the login view controller to be presented and dismissed).

Which is better would depend on your specific requirements.

I generally use the first method to clearly separate the logged-out vs logged-in experiences in my apps. This is particularly useful if your "logged in" view controllers actually require a logged-in user to function correctly (such as fetching data for that user from a server, etc). If you simply don't initialize the views at all until the user logs in, you don't have to worry about handling a whole extra "not logged in" state for those views.

Comment: Thank you I had actually put option 2 backwards. I do mean to start with the rootViewController as the tabBarController. And I understand your point with which one you would use, great advice, thank you! One question though.. If you were to use option 2, how would you dismiss "yourLoginViewController" upon successful login? Resetting the `rootViewController`?

Comment: If you presented it modally, you would just call `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:`